# display if category has no subcategories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want the output of the wordpress woocommerce product categories like this:

```
<ul>

<li>categorie-with-sub
   <ul>
     <li>sub 1</li>
     <li>sub 2</li>
   <ul>
</li>

<li>category-without-sub</li>

<li>categorie-with-sub
       <ul>
         <li>sub 1</li>
         <li>sub 2</li>
       <ul>
 </li>
```

but with the code below it is:

```
<li>categorie-with-sub
   <ul>
     <li>sub 1</li>
     <li>sub 2</li>
   <ul>
</li>

<li>category-without-sub</li><ul>

<li>categorie-with-sub
       <ul>
         <li>sub 1</li>
         <li>sub 2</li>
       <ul>
 </li>
```

What should I do to solve the problem? I tried many ways. There must be something that will do my requests.

```
   <?php
$taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
$orderby      = 'name';
$show_count   = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title        = '';
$empty        = 0;

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title,
  'hide_empty'   => $empty
); 
?>

<?php $all_categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {  

    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {?>


<?php   $category_id = $cat->term_id;
        $thumbnail_id   = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        echo '<li class="has-sub"><img src="'.$image.'"  width="29px" height="29px" class="cat-img"/><a href="#"><span>'. $cat->name .'</span></a><ul>';

$cats = get_categories($args);
        $args2 = array(
          'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
          'child_of'     => 0,
          'parent'       => $category_id,
          'orderby'      => $orderby,
          'show_count'   => $show_count,
          'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
          'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
          'title_li'     => $title,
          'hide_empty'   => 1,

        );


        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
        if($sub_cats) {
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
        if($sub_cats->$sub_category == 0) {
            $thumbnail_id   = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $sub_category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );

            echo '<li><img src="'.$image.'"  width="29px" height="29px" class="cat-img"/><a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'.$sub_category->name.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        }?>


<?php   } 
 } ?>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$term = get_queried_object();

$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
'parent'    => $term->term_id,
'hide_empty' => false
) );
// print_r($children); // uncomment to examine for debugging
if($children) { // get_terms will return false if tax does not exist or term wasn't found.
    // term has children
}
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$term = get_queried_object();

$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
'parent'    => $term->term_id,
'hide_empty' => false
) );
// print_r($children); // uncomment to examine for debugging
if($children) { // get_terms will return false if tax does not exist or term wasn't found.
    // term has children
}
```

This worked but had to be slightly modified.  I had to change

```
$term = get_queried_object();
```

to

```
global $wp_query;
$term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
```